# Display 0 when COUNT() returns nothing

Tags: sql, oracle, join, count, subquery

I'm trying to find the devices that are stuck in a certain status, and group them by their types. I query the database for the `count()` of devices in that status, and then do a couple of checks to see if those devices meet the criteria. However, it is not showing the types that do not have any `count()`. I need all types to be shown, even if there is nothing to `count()`.

For example, currently I have this:

```
TYPE   COUNT(DEVICE.NAME)
TYPE1                 200
TYPE2                 100
TYPE3                  50
```

I need it to come back like this:

```
TYPE   COUNT(DEVICE.NAME)
TYPE1                 200
TYPE2                 100
TYPE3                  50
TYPE4                   0
TYPE5                   0
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT device.type, count(device.name)
FROM device
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT type, name
                  FROM device) b
  ON device.name = b.name
WHERE device.changedon < (((SYSDATE - DATE '1970-01-01') * 24 * 60 * 60) - (90 * 24 * 60 * 60))
  AND device.status != 6 AND device.status != 8 AND device.status != 13
GROUP BY device.type
ORDER BY count(device.name) DESC;
```

It was later realized that the join on table `b` was unnecessary, but I will leave it in the question so that the answers still accurately reflect the question.

I have tried all types of joins on the subquery and the results are the same.

Comment: I realized that the join on h471 was unnecessary and I have removed it from the SQL statement. Sorry about any confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `left outer join`, you need to use it for all the joins in the query (typically).  Otherwise, you might be "undoing" the earlier join.

However, I don't think that is your only issue.  The expression `count(d.name)` has to return at least 1 (unless `name` can be `NULL`).

```
SELECT d.type, count(h471.id)
FROM device d INNER JOIN
     (SELECT type, name
      FROM device
     ) b
     ON d.name = b.name
WHERE d.changedon < (((SYSDATE - DATE '1970-01-01') * 24 * 60 * 60) - (90 * 24 * 60 * 60)) and
      d.status != 6 AND d.status != 8 AND d.status != 13
GROUP BY d.type;
```

When using outer joins, you also have to pay attention to the `where` clause.  In this case, though, you are only refering to the `device` table.  If the switch to `left outer join` doesn't fix the problem, then the issue is in the `where` clause -- it is filtering out the additional devices.  If that is the case, then move the `where` clause to a conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT d.type,
       sum(case when d.changedon < (((SYSDATE - DATE '1970-01-01') * 24 * 60 * 60) - (90 * 24 * 60 * 60)) and
                       d.status != 6 AND d.status != 8 AND d.status != 13
                  then 1 else 0
            end)
FROM device d LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT type, name
      FROM device
     ) b
     ON d.name = b.name 
GROUP BY d.type;
```

You might be able to move some of the conditions back to the `where` clause for performance reasons.

Also, I don't get the join to table `b`.  It would just be multiplying the number of rows (if multiple rows in `device` have the same name) or doing nothing.

Comment: Please see my comment on the main post about the join on h471.

Comment: @AustinMoore . . . I made modifications so the answer is consistent with the changed question.

Comment: Thanks! Your second statement solved my issue. I was also able to remove the join to table `b` and have it still work. I had the join there because through my online searches, it looked like I needed to use something similar to that join. I should have mentioned that the statement worked before I included the where clause. As you suspected, the issue was with the where clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff assuming that `name` is a unique value in the device table (which appears may be the case but am not certain of), then you can remove the entire `b` subquery in your 2nd example that uses `SUM` w/ the `CASE` statement.  Also forgot to take `h471.id` out of the COUNT in the first query.

Comment: @BateTech . . . I totally agree, but the code is there *so* intentionally that it seems that it has a purpose.  A mysterious purpose.

Comment: @GordonLinoff what do you think would be appropriate in this situation? Should I remove the statement from the original question, because as it was indeed doing nothing? Or should I leave it? I'm leaning towards the first one, so the question won't confuse any people who stumble across this question in the future.

Comment: @AustinMoore . . . I'd go with the more conservative approach and not change the question.  You can edit the question and point out that the `join` to `b` is unnecessary, but if you remove it entirely, then all the answers will look that much more misleading.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need something like

```
SELECT type, SUM(COUNT_RESULT)
  FROM (

          SELECT device.type, 0 COUNT_RESULT
          FROM device

          UNION ALL

          SELECT device.type, count(1)
          FROM device, h471
          WHERE device.recnum = h471.id
            AND device.changedon < (((SYSDATE - DATE '1970-01-01') * 24 * 60 * 60) - (90 * 24 * 60 * 60))
            AND device.status != 6 AND device.status != 8 AND device.status != 13

)        
GROUP BY type
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer also solved my issue. It is similar to @GordonLinoff's answer. However, because Gordon explained the problem and the solution, I will select his as the correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like what you want can be achieved by making the whole query into a subquery and applying COALESCE to get 0 for missing results.

```
SELECT d0.type, COALESCE(d.cnt,0) FROM device d0
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT device.type, count(device.name) AS cnt
  FROM device
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT type, name
                    FROM device) b
    ON device.name = b.name
  WHERE device.changedon < (((SYSDATE - DATE '1970-01-01') * 24 * 60 * 60) - (90 * 24 * 60 * 60))
  AND device.status != 6 AND device.status != 8 AND device.status != 13
  GROUP BY device.type) d
ORDER BY COALESCE(d.cnt,0) DESC;
```

Comment: `COALESCE()` does not seem to work when implemented as you suggested. I am still missing the types with 0 count.

Comment: `COALESCE` will not help in this case unless the `COUNT` was within the subquery `b`.  With `COUNT` as it is in the original query, it will never return NULL, so the `COALESCE` will not have any effect.  `COUNT` on a column will all NULL values will still return 0.

Comment: You're right, I overlooked that. I'm pretty sure I fixed that now.